# ¿Cómo devolver SCOPE_IDENTITY() desde procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estoy tratando de devolver el SCOPE_IDENTITY() de un procedimiento almacenado (exactamente de la ultima instrucción INSERT que se ejecuta en este)a mi aplicacion c# …Escribi este código pero siempre me devuelve – 1

```
USE [DB_A40B8F_FloraNueva]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Sp_ActualizarProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual]    Script Date: 01/11/2018 10:48:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ActualizarProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual] 
       (
            @IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual INT,
            @Identificador UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @IdProductor INT,
            @Fecha DateTime,
            @ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente BIT,
            @OtraPersonaPresente VARCHAR(500),
            @Motivo VARCHAR(500),
            @Observaciones VARCHAR(500), 
            @Recomendaciones VARCHAR(500),
            @Otros VARCHAR(500),
            @Estado VARCHAR(50),
            @Usuario VARCHAR(50),
            @Dispositivo VARCHAR(50),
            @FechaCreacion DATETIME,
            @FechaCreacionUtc VARCHAR(50),
            @FechaModificacion DATETIME,
            @FechaModificacionUtc VARCHAR(50),
            @Transaccion VARCHAR(50)
       )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TRANCOUNTER INT = 0;
DECLARE @ID INT;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET  TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

   BEGIN TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK]

   BEGIN TRY

                IF (@IdProductor = 0)  BEGIN   SET @IdProductor = (SELECT IdProductor FROM Productor WHERE Identificador = @Identificador); END 
                IF (LEN(@OtraPersonaPresente) = 0) BEGIN SET @OtraPersonaPresente = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Motivo) = 0) BEGIN SET @Motivo = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Observaciones) = 0) BEGIN SET @Observaciones = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Recomendaciones) = 0) BEGIN SET @Recomendaciones = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Otros) = 0) BEGIN SET @Otros = NULL; END


         INSERT INTO ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividualTrack (Identificador,IdProductor,Fecha,ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,OtraPersonaPresente,Motivo,Observaciones,Recomendaciones,Otros,Estado,Usuario,Dispositivo,FechaCreacion,FechaCreacionUtc,FechaModificacion,FechaModificacionUtc,Transaccion)
                              VALUES  (@Identificador,@IdProductor,@Fecha,@ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,@OtraPersonaPresente,@Motivo, @Observaciones , @Recomendaciones,@Otros,@Estado,@Usuario,@Dispositivo,@FechaCreacion,@FechaCreacionUtc,@FechaModificacion,@FechaModificacionUtc,@Transaccion)


     SAVE TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK]
     SET @TRANCOUNTER = 1
      BEGIN TRAN [PRODUCTOR]


     IF (@IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual > 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual SET
            IdProductor = @IdProductor,
            Fecha = @Fecha ,
            ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente = @ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente ,
            OtraPersonaPresente = @OtraPersonaPresente ,
            Motivo  = @Motivo ,
            Observaciones = @Observaciones,
            Recomendaciones = @Recomendaciones ,
            Otros  = @Otros ,
            Estado = @Estado 
            WHERE Identificador = @Identificador AND IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual= @IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual;

            SET @ID = @IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual
        END 
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual (Identificador,IdProductor,Fecha,ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,OtraPersonaPresente,Motivo,Observaciones,Recomendaciones,Otros,Estado)
                              VALUES  (@Identificador,@IdProductor,@Fecha,@ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,@OtraPersonaPresente,@Motivo,@Observaciones,@Recomendaciones,@Otros,@Estado)

           SET @ID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() )
        END


    SAVE TRAN [PRODUCTOR];
    COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK];
    COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTOR];


   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK] ;
        ROLLBACK TRAN  [PRODUCTOR]; 
        COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK]; 
        COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTOR]; 
        SET @ID  = -2;
   END CATCH

      SELECT @ID
END ;
```

Este es mi codigo en la aplicacion

```
public int InsertarActualizarProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual(List <FloraNuevaProductor.ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual> MiItem, string identificador, string nombreSP)
        {
            int resultado = new int();
            object id = new object();
            SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
            using (Conexion)
            {
                Conexion.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(nombreSP, Conexion);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (FloraNuevaProductor.ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual Item in MiItem)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual", Item.IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identificador", identificador);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProductor", Item.IdProductor); //Relacion Productor
                    if (Item.Fecha == Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001 0:00:00")) Item.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Item.Fecha);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente", Item.ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtraPersonaPresente", Item.OtraPersonaPresente);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Motivo", Item.Motivo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observaciones", Item.Observaciones);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recomendaciones", Item.Recomendaciones);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Otros", Item.Otros);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", Item.Estado);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Item.Usuario);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dispositivo", Item.Dispositivo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCreacion", DateTime.Now);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCreacionUtc", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(Engine.EngineData.dateFormatUtc));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaModificacion", DateTime.Now);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaModificacionUtc", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(Engine.EngineData.dateFormatUtc));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transaccion", Item.Transaccion);
                    id = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (id != null)
                    {
                        resultado = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                    }
                }
                Conexion.Close();
            }
            return resultado;
        }
```

Comment: Hola Efrain, ya verificaste que efectivamente esté insertando datos en la tabla ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual?

Comment: Siiii ...Inserta Bien

Answer (score 1):

Te falto agregar un parámetro de retorno para obtener el resultado:

```
SqlParameter retValue = cmd.Parameters.Add("return", SqlDbType.Int);
retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

y luego de ejecutado el store procedure, obtienes el valor:

```
retValue.Value
```

Saludos!

Comment: Algo que no entiedo si puedes especificar tu respuesta algo mas seria genial...por que ExecuteNonQuery es la sentecia que ejecuta el Procedimiento donde van tus lineas???

Answer (score 0):

SP

```
USE [DB_A40B8F_FloraNueva]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Sp_ActualizarProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual]    Script Date: 02/11/2018 11:08:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ActualizarProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual] 
       (
            @IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual INT,
            @Identificador UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @IdProductor INT,
            @Fecha DateTime,
            @ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente BIT,
            @OtraPersonaPresente VARCHAR(500),
            @Motivo VARCHAR(500),
            @Observaciones VARCHAR(500), 
            @Recomendaciones VARCHAR(500),
            @Otros VARCHAR(500),
            @Estado VARCHAR(50),
            @Usuario VARCHAR(50),
            @Dispositivo VARCHAR(50),
            @FechaCreacion DATETIME,
            @FechaCreacionUtc VARCHAR(50),
            @FechaModificacion DATETIME,
            @FechaModificacionUtc VARCHAR(50),
            @Transaccion VARCHAR(50)
       )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TRANCOUNTER INT = 0;
DECLARE @ID INT;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET  TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

   BEGIN TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK]

   BEGIN TRY

                IF (@IdProductor = 0)  BEGIN   SET @IdProductor = (SELECT IdProductor FROM Productor WHERE Identificador = @Identificador); END 
                IF (LEN(@OtraPersonaPresente) = 0) BEGIN SET @OtraPersonaPresente = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Motivo) = 0) BEGIN SET @Motivo = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Observaciones) = 0) BEGIN SET @Observaciones = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Recomendaciones) = 0) BEGIN SET @Recomendaciones = NULL; END
                IF (LEN(@Otros) = 0) BEGIN SET @Otros = NULL; END


         INSERT INTO ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividualTrack (Identificador,IdProductor,Fecha,ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,OtraPersonaPresente,Motivo,Observaciones,Recomendaciones,Otros,Estado,Usuario,Dispositivo,FechaCreacion,FechaCreacionUtc,FechaModificacion,FechaModificacionUtc,Transaccion)
                              VALUES  (@Identificador,@IdProductor,@Fecha,@ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,@OtraPersonaPresente,@Motivo, @Observaciones , @Recomendaciones,@Otros,@Estado,@Usuario,@Dispositivo,@FechaCreacion,@FechaCreacionUtc,@FechaModificacion,@FechaModificacionUtc,@Transaccion)


     SAVE TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK]
     SET @TRANCOUNTER = 1
      BEGIN TRAN [PRODUCTOR]


     IF (@IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual > 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual SET
            IdProductor = @IdProductor,
            Fecha = @Fecha ,
            ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente = @ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente ,
            OtraPersonaPresente = @OtraPersonaPresente ,
            Motivo  = @Motivo ,
            Observaciones = @Observaciones,
            Recomendaciones = @Recomendaciones ,
            Otros  = @Otros ,
            Estado = @Estado 
            WHERE Identificador = @Identificador AND IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual= @IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual;

            SET @ID = @IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual
        END 
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual (Identificador,IdProductor,Fecha,ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,OtraPersonaPresente,Motivo,Observaciones,Recomendaciones,Otros,Estado)
                              VALUES  (@Identificador,@IdProductor,@Fecha,@ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente,@OtraPersonaPresente,@Motivo,@Observaciones,@Recomendaciones,@Otros,@Estado)

           SET @ID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
        END


    SAVE TRAN [PRODUCTOR];
    COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK];
    COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTOR];


   END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK] ;
        ROLLBACK TRAN  [PRODUCTOR]; 
        COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTORTRACK]; 
        COMMIT TRAN [PRODUCTOR]; 
        SET @ID  = -2;
   END CATCH

      SELECT @ID
END ;
```

C#

```
 public int InsertarActualizarProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual(List <FloraNuevaProductor.ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual> MiItem, string identificador, string nombreSP)
        {
            int resultado = new int();
            object id = new object();
            SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
            using (Conexion)
            {
                Conexion.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(nombreSP, Conexion);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (FloraNuevaProductor.ProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual Item in MiItem)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual", Item.IdProductorAbejasNativasVisitaIndividual);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identificador", identificador);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProductor", Item.IdProductor); //Relacion Productor
                    if (Item.Fecha == Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001 0:00:00")) Item.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Item.Fecha);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente", Item.ElMeliponicultorEstaPresente);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OtraPersonaPresente", Item.OtraPersonaPresente);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Motivo", Item.Motivo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Observaciones", Item.Observaciones);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recomendaciones", Item.Recomendaciones);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Otros", Item.Otros);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", Item.Estado);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Item.Usuario);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dispositivo", Item.Dispositivo);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCreacion", DateTime.Now);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCreacionUtc", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(Engine.EngineData.dateFormatUtc));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaModificacion", DateTime.Now);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaModificacionUtc", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(Engine.EngineData.dateFormatUtc));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transaccion", Item.Transaccion);
                    id = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (id != null)
                    {
                        resultado = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                    }
                }
                Conexion.Close();
            }
            return resultado;
        }
```